# active or backup DOWN+ openshift + nodejs

Tags: node.js, openshift, haproxy

i deploy my nodejs application on openshift. it is start and working fine. when is check ctl_app status it shows that app is started and running.

but in haproxy-status it not coming up. it shows  "active or backup DOWN".so i can't access my app via url

i check logs of node application it is running perfectly.

please help me. anyone know how i can solve this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution, as my app haven't root(/) api so when haproxy check status via get on root path(/).

it get null when haproxy call app for check status. so haproxy asume that app still no came up.